# Download files in django from database and also view pdf file in that

Tags: python, django

Well, I am trying to make a simple app in django in which I upload files from admin panel. The user is greeted with a simple search page in which he enters an id which thus needs to produce the related file. The file is to be in pdf format. So if there is a way I could view the pdf file in the browser and a download button which downloads the file. The code is hosted on Github, the link is https://github.com/tahseen09/delhipatho

Comment: You dont have urls.py in your report app.

Comment: and do you want to upload file in sign in or retrieve it?

Comment: Please explain what do you try to do with sign-up form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'` to your `settings.py`

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
from report.models import query

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            query =  query.objects.filter(id__exact =form.cleaned_data['id'])
            return render(request, 'ans.html', {'query':query})
    else:
        form = Form()
    return render(request,"index.html", {'form':form})
```

**ans.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delhi Patho</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/main.css' %}" />
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">
    <p><a href="{{query.repo.url}}">Download</p>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="{% static 'assets/js/main.js' %}"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the id doesn't exist in database. It will throw error. How to create a condition so that it returns a message or the index page. By the way, thanks a lot.

Comment: It will not throw any error just you will get an empty query in the template which will redirect to none when clicked. You can use query = get_object_or_404(query, pk=id) to have user noticed that this is a bad request.